# Micronaut automatic conversion of HTTP request parameters

Tags: java, type-conversion, micronaut

I am currently struggling trying to setup micronaut in order to automatically convert parameters from the http request uri into pojos.

Specifically I want to achieve something like that:

```
@Controller
public class FooBarBazController {

    @Get("/{foo}/{bar}")
    public Baz doSomething(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
        return new Baz(foo, bar);
    }

}
```

Assuming `Foo` and `Bar` can be constructed from a string value.

The only response I got from the server is

```
{
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "/forever/young",
      "templated": false
    }
  },
  "message": "Required argument [Foo foo] not specified",
  "path": "/foo"
}
```

I have already tried the following:

- Define a `@Factory` that registers two beans: `TypeConverter<String, Foo>` and `TypeConverter<String, Bar>`
- Define the parameters as `@QueryValue("foo")` and `@QueryValue("bar")` respectively
- Define the parameters as `@PathVariable("foo")` and `@PathVariable("bar")` respectively

None of that seems to help, and I cannot find any reference online that resemble my problem.

Does anybody know how can I instruct the framework to perform the automatic conversion and binding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Micronaut 1.3 the only thing required is to define a `TypeConverter` for `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
@Singleton
public class FooTypeConverter implements TypeConverter<String, Foo> {
    @Override
    public Optional<Foo> convert(String fooString, Class<Foo> targetType, ConversionContext context) {
        return new Foo(fooString);
    }
}
```

...

```
@Singleton
public class BarTypeConverter implements TypeConverter<String, Bar> {
    @Override
    public Optional<Bar> convert(String barString, Class<Bar> targetType, ConversionContext context) {
        return new Bar(barString);
    }
}
```

That's it.

In your controller, you can then just use `Foo` and `Bar` like any other type that Micronaut knows about:

```
@Get("/foo/{foo}")
public HttpResponse<FooResponse> getFoo(@PathVariable Foo foo) {
    ...
}
```

...

```
@Get("/bar/{bar}")
public HttpResponse<BarResponse> getBar(@PathVariable Bar bar) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use the [newly introduced](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/commit/b0a6be7ed69b75fede1e3ce5c82aa9cdc6d08861/) `@PathVariable` in version `1.0.3` you will be all set.